# How to change the length of the Plot?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a problem with the fact that I want the lines Plot, at crossing the candle stopped and did not go to the right on the chart, and those that have not had a crossing with a candle, went constantly to the right. Is it possible to do this with Plot?

```
lengthGroupTitle = "Настройка уровней"
leftLenH = input.int(title="Множитель уровня ликвидации, относительно ТФ", defval=100, minval=1, group=lengthGroupTitle)
rightLenH = leftLenH

leftLenL = leftLenH
rightLenL = leftLenL
ph = ta.pivothigh(leftLenH, rightLenH)
pl = ta.pivotlow(leftLenL, rightLenL)

drawLabel(_offset, _pivot, _style, _color, _textColor) =>
    if not na(_pivot)
        label.new(bar_index[_offset], _pivot, str.tostring(_pivot, format.mintick), style=_style, color=_color, textcolor=_textColor)


atr1 = ta.atr(10)


atr2 = ta.atr(10)


atr3 = ta.atr(10)


atr4 = ta.atr(10)
perc_dist4 = int(0.3)

atr5 = ta.atr(10)
perc_dist5 = int(1.2)

atr6 = ta.atr(10)
perc_dist6 = int(3)

pos1 = close + close *0.49 /100
pos2 = close + close *1.47 /100
pos3 = close + close *3.3 /100

pos4 = close - close *0.49 /100
pos5 = close - close *1.47 /100
pos6 = close - close *3.3 /100

c = ta.pivothigh(leftLenH, rightLenH)
b = ta.pivotlow(leftLenL, rightLenL)

plotshape(c ? pos1: na , "100х Ликвидации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "100х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(c ? pos2: na , "50х Ликвилации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "50х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(c ? pos3: na , "25х Ликвидации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "25х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)

plotshape(b ? pos4: na , "100х Ликвидации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "100х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(b ? pos5: na , "50х Ликвилации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "50х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(b ? pos6: na , "25х Ликвидации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "25х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)

//
long_short = 0
long_last = c and (nz(long_short[1]) == 0 or nz(long_short[1]) == -1)
short_last = b and (nz(long_short[1]) == 0 or nz(long_short[1]) == 1)
long_short := long_last ? 1 : short_last ? -1 : long_short[1]


//Logic
longPrice = ta.valuewhen(long_last, close, 0)
shortPrice = ta.valuewhen(short_last, close, 0)
//Fixed liquidation
longStop = longPrice * (1 + (0.49/100))
longStop2 = longPrice * (1 + (1.47/100))
longStop3 = longPrice * (1 + (3.3/100))

ShortStop1 = shortPrice * (1 - (0.49/100))
ShortStop2 = shortPrice * (1 - (1.47/100))
ShortStop3 = shortPrice * (1 - (3.3/100))
//plot sltp lines
plot(long_short == 1 ? longStop :na , style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.blue, linewidth=1, title="100x Линия Лонг", trackprice=true)
plot(long_short == 1 ? longStop2 :na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.black, linewidth=1, title="50x Линия Лонг", trackprice=true)
plot(long_short == 1 ? longStop3 : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.red, linewidth=1, title="25x Линия Лонг", trackprice=true)

plot(long_short == -1 ? ShortStop1 : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.blue, linewidth=1, title="100x Линия Шорт", trackprice=true)
plot(long_short == -1 ? ShortStop2 : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.black, linewidth=1, title="100x Линия Шорт", trackprice=true)
plot(long_short == -1 ? ShortStop3 : na, style=plot.style_linebr, color=color.red, linewidth=1, title="100x Линия Шорт", trackprice=true)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `line` for this which in my opinion would be easier.

However, since you specifically asked for plots, you can assign `na` to your plot when the price crosses your line.

Here is an example for you that plots the previous month's high, and it stops ploting this line, when the price crosses it.

```
// This source code is subject to the terms of the Mozilla Public License 2.0 at https://mozilla.org/MPL/2.0/
// © vitruvius

//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay=true)

prev_month_high = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, "M", high[1], barmerge.gaps_on, barmerge.lookahead_on)
var float high_line = na

high_line := not na(prev_month_high) ? prev_month_high : high_line  // Assign new previous high when it is a new month

is_high_cross = ta.cross(high, high_line)
is_low_cross = ta.cross(low, high_line)

high_line := (is_high_cross or is_low_cross) ? na : high_line       // Assign na when the price crosses the line

plot(high_line, style=plot.style_linebr)
```

[image]

Comment: Late seeing your answer, started working with the line, and came to a small error in drawing the lines downward "in array get function index 0 is out of bounds array size is 0"

Answer (score 0):

```
pos1 = close + close * (0.48 /100)
pos2 = close + close * (1.47 /100)
pos3 = close + close * (3.3 /100)

pos4 = close - close * (0.49 /100)
pos5 = close - close * (1.47 /100)
pos6 = close - close * (3.3 /100)

c = ta.pivothigh(leftLenH,rightLenH)
b = ta.pivotlow(leftLenL, rightLenL)

plotshape(c ? pos1: na , "100х Ликвидации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "100х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(c ? pos2: na , "50х Ликвилации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "50х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(c ? pos3: na , "25х Ликвидации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "25х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)

plotshape(b ? pos4: na , "100х Ликвидации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "100х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(b ? pos5: na , "50х Ликвилации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "50х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)
plotshape(b ? pos6: na , "25х Ликвидации Лонг", shape.circle, location.absolute, color.black, 0, "25х Ликвидации", (color.black), size=size.tiny)

//////Lines//////////

bars = +500
n = 1

var line[]  highs = array.new_line()  // declare an empty array to store our lines in 
var line[]  highs2 = array.new_line()  // declare an empty array to store our lines in 
var line[]  highs3 = array.new_line()  // declare an empty array to store our lines in 
var line[]  highs4 = array.new_line()  // declare an empty array to store our lines in 
var line[]  highs5 = array.new_line()  // declare an empty array to store our lines in 
var line[]  highs6 = array.new_line()  // declare an empty array to store our lines in 
//Lines
bull = b
bear = c
highestHigh = pos1
highestHigh2 = pos2
highestHigh3 = pos3
lowerlow1 = pos4
lowerlow2 = pos5
lowerlow3 = pos6
if bear     // instead of just drawing a line, we push it into an array, a list of lines so we can loop through the list and perform actions on all lines 
    array.unshift(highs, line.new(bar_index, highestHigh, bar_index + bars, highestHigh, extend=extend.none, color=color.red))
    array.unshift(highs2, line.new(bar_index, highestHigh2, bar_index + bars, highestHigh2, extend=extend.none, color=color.red))
    array.unshift(highs3, line.new(bar_index, highestHigh3, bar_index + bars, highestHigh3, extend=extend.none, color=color.red))
if bull
    array.unshift(highs4, line.new(bar_index, lowerlow1, bar_index + bars, lowerlow1, extend=extend.none, color=color.red))
    array.unshift(highs5, line.new(bar_index, lowerlow2, bar_index + bars, lowerlow2, extend=extend.none, color=color.red))
    array.unshift(highs6, line.new(bar_index, lowerlow3, bar_index + bars, lowerlow3, extend=extend.none, color=color.red))


for i = (array.size(highs) > 0 ? array.size(highs)-1 : na) to 0                   
    l1 = line.get_price(array.get(highs,i), bar_index) 
    if close > l1                                     
        line.set_x2(array.get(highs,i), bar_index)    
        array.remove(highs, i)                        
        
for i2 = (array.size(highs2) > 0 ? array.size(highs2)-1 : na) to 0                   
    l2 = line.get_price(array.get(highs2,i2), bar_index) 
    if close > l2                                      
        line.set_x2(array.get(highs2,i2), bar_index)    
        array.remove(highs2, i2)                        
        
for i3 = (array.size(highs3) > 0 ? array.size(highs3)-1 : na) to 0                   
    l3 = line.get_price(array.get(highs3,i3), bar_index) 
    if close > l3                                     
        line.set_x2(array.get(highs3,i3), bar_index)    
        array.remove(highs3, i3)            
    
for i4 = (array.size(highs4) > 0 ? array.size(highs4)-1 : na) to 0                   
    l4 = line.get_price(array.get(highs4,i4), bar_index) 
    if low > l4                                     
        line.set_x2(array.get(highs4,i4), bar_index)    
        array.remove(highs4, i4)                        
        
for i5 = (array.size(highs5) > 0 ? array.size(highs5)-1 : na) to 0                   
    l5 = line.get_price(array.get(highs5,i5), bar_index) 
    if low > l5                                      
        line.set_x2(array.get(highs5,i5), bar_index)    
        array.remove(highs5, i5)                        
        
for i6 = (array.size(highs6) > 0 ? array.size(highs6)-1 : na) to 0                   
    l6 = line.get_price(array.get(highs6,i6), bar_index) 
    if low > l6                                    
        line.set_x2(array.get(highs6,i6), bar_index)    
        array.remove(highs6, i6)        


for x = (array.size(highs) > 0 ? array.size(highs)-1 : na) to 0                        
    line.set_x2(array.get(highs, x), bar_index+bars)  

for x2 = (array.size(highs2) > 0 ? array.size(highs2)-1 : na) to 0                        
    line.set_x2(array.get(highs2, x2), bar_index+bars)  

for x3 = (array.size(highs3) > 0 ? array.size(highs3)-1 : na) to 0                        
    line.set_x2(array.get(highs3, x3), bar_index+bars)  

for x4 = (array.size(highs4) > 0 ? array.size(highs4)-1 : na) to 0                        
    line.set_x2(array.get(highs4, x4), bar_index+bars)  

for x5 = (array.size(highs5) > 0 ? array.size(highs5)-1 : na) to 0                        
    line.set_x2(array.get(highs5, x5), bar_index+bars)  

for x6 = (array.size(highs6) > 0 ? array.size(highs6)-1 : na) to 0                        
    line.set_x2(array.get(highs6, x6), bar_index+bars)
```

Realizing that the lines would look more adequate, I rewrote the code a bit. Thus, for some reason, part of the points I have a line, some do not, it is not quite clear where I have a mistake.....But on the backtests, the lines work as they should, except for the lower ones. The problem there is most likely in the argument itself
[image]

Comment: Please ask a new question for this.

Comment: Yes, I have just made up a new question.Thanks